# Join several tables (to fetch user info as 1 row), but one of them is optional (user avatar)

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, left-join, postgresql-8.4

Given a user name in a Drupal 7.17 database using PostgreSQL 8.4.13 I am trying to fetch user info (uid, city, gender, avatar) distributed over several tables.

The avatar (the `f.filename` below) is however optional - some users don't have it.

For users, that do have avatars my query works well:

```
#  select
        u.uid,
        /* u.pass, */
        f.filename,
        g.field_gender_value,
        c.field_city_value
from
        drupal_users u,
        drupal_file_managed f,
        drupal_field_data_field_gender g,
        drupal_field_data_field_city c
where
        u.name='Alex' and
        u.picture=f.fid and
        g.entity_id=u.uid and
        c.entity_id=u.uid
;
 uid |         filename         | field_gender_value | field_city_value
-----+--------------------------+--------------------+------------------
   1 | picture-1-1312223092.jpg | Male               | Bochum
(1 row)
```

However for users, who don't have avatar I get empty result.

When I omit the `drupal_file_managed f` table - it works again:

```
#  select
        u.uid,
        /* u.pass, */

        g.field_gender_value,
        c.field_city_value
from
        drupal_users u,

        drupal_field_data_field_gender g,
        drupal_field_data_field_city c
where
        u.name='mvp' and

        g.entity_id=u.uid and
        c.entity_id=u.uid
;
  uid  | field_gender_value | field_city_value
-------+--------------------+------------------
 18539 | Male               | Moscow
(1 row)
```

How could I modify my join statement to **ensure that it always returns 1 row** for valid users - regardless if they have avatar or not? The `f.filename` column can be null for the latter cases.

Do I want a [left outer join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/tutorial-join.html) here? (I'm afraid it will return several rows instead of 1).

Comment: Can a user have more than 1 avatar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With COALESCE() you can even plug in a default value, if the filename appears to be missing:

```
SELECT u.uid AS uid
        , COALESCE(f.filename, 'goatsex.jpg') AS filename
        , g.field_gender_value AS gender_value
        , c.field_city_value AS city_value
FROM drupal_users u
JOIN drupal_field_data_field_gender g ON g.entity_id=u.uid 
JOIN drupal_field_data_field_city c ON c.entity_id=u.uid
LEFT JOIN drupal_file_managed f ON u.picture=f.fid 
WHERE u.name='Alex' 
        ;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you want a left outer join. It will return several rows only if there are users that have more than one avatar, but the same is true for inner joins.

Comment: Thanks! No, they can only have 0 or 1 avatars. I'm still struggling with the syntax though....

Comment: What is your problem with the syntax? `LEFT JOIN ... ON a = b`. What does not work?

Comment: `select ..... FROM drupal_users u LEFT OUTER JOIN
        drupal_file_managed f,
        drupal_field_data_field_gender g,
        drupal_field_data_field_city c ......` gives me syntax error after the first comma

Comment: That's because you are missing the ON clause before the comma

Comment: You need to convert all your joins to use the same syntax: e.g. from a inner join b on a.id = b.a_id left join c on c.id = b.c_id etc etc. i.e. remove those join conditions from the where clause and put them in the join clauses (except for your filter conditions if appropriate).